# How do you add a counter to the Facebook share button (generated via FB.ui)?

Tags: javascript, facebook

This is how I'm generating my share button:

```
  <a href="#" class="share-btn">Share to Facebook</a>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  function fb_share() {
    var fbMsg = $('.lesson_lt_share_popup').text().trim()
    FB.ui( {
      method: 'feed',
      name: "Chinese Learn Online | Progressive Mandarin Course",
      link: "http://www.chineselearnonline.com/level-test/",
      picture: "http://www.chineselearnonline.com/wp-content/themes/clo/assets/img/images/clo-fb-white.png",
      description: fbMsg
    }, function(response) {
        // do nothing
    });
  }

  // add click event to link using jQuery
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.share-btn').on( 'click', fb_share );
  });
```

But I count find anything about generating a counter in the [official docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart/v2.3).

How do do that?

Comment: Can you try tracking the clicks on the element.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generating a counter manually is a pain, you would have to read the count with the Graph API. The easiest solution is to use the official Share Button Plugin instead of `FB.ui`, as it includes a counter already: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button

It takes all the neccessary data from the [Open Graph Tags](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#tags).

Btw, the feed dialog is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Add attribute `data-layout="button_count"`.

```
<a href="#" class="share-btn" data-layout="button_count">Share to Facebook</a>
```